# How to get the output of the predictions without the evaluations in Python

Tags: python, pytorch

So maybe this is a stupid question, but I'm trying to learn about action recognition with MoViNet model. They have an example code in the github repo (https://github.com/Atze00/MoViNet-pytorch), is the following one:

https://colab.research.google.com/github/Atze00/MoViNet-pytorch/blob/main/movinet_tutorial.ipynb

My question is, how can I upload my own '.mp4' video and get the predictions (aka categories)? I don't have the lables or annotations for those videos, but I wanted tu use the pretrained model that is provided. I wrote this code:

```
'''
example_train = torchvision.datasets.HMDB51('examples/'video1.mp4'', ?????, num_frames,frame_rate=5,
                                                step_between_clips = clip_steps, fold=1, train=True,
                                                transform=transform, num_workers=2)


example_test = torchvision.datasets.HMDB51('content/video2.mp4', ????, num_frames,frame_rate=5,
                                                step_between_clips = clip_steps, fold=1, train=False,
                                                transform=transform_test, num_workers=2)

train_loader = DataLoader(example_train, batch_size=Bs_Train, shuffle=True)
test_loader  = DataLoader(example_test, batch_size=Bs_Test, shuffle=False)
'''

trloss_val, tsloss_val = [], []
model.classifier[3] = torch.nn.Conv3d(2048, 51, (1,1,1))
optimz = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.00005)
for epoch in range(1, N_EPOCHS + 1):
    print('Epoch:', epoch)
    train_iter(model, optimz, 'examples/video1.mp4', trloss_val)
    evaluate(model, 'examples/video1.mp4', tsloss_val)

 
print('Execution time:', '{:5.2f}'.format(time.time() - start_time), 'seconds')
```

But is not useful since I don't have the annotations for these videos, I just want the output of the predictions without the evaluations.

Answer (score 0):

The test function will look like this (just a draft):

```
def test(model, data_load):
    model.eval()
    samples = len(data_load.dataset)
    csamp = 0
    model.clean_activation_buffers()
    with torch.no_grad():
        for data in data_load:
            output = F.log_softmax(model(data.cuda()), dim=1)
            _, pred = torch.max(output, dim=1)
            csamp += pred.eq(target.cuda()).sum()
            model.clean_activation_buffers()
    
    return preds
```

**You need to write your own dataset to load the video you want to predict**. You'll need to read about [Pytorch Datasets & DataLoaders](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/basics/data_tutorial.html) and [Writing Custom Pytorch Datasets, DataLoaders and Transforms](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/data_loading_tutorial.html). The simple idea is when you train, your `TrainDataset` will return videos and annotations (used to calculate loss and update the model). As for prediction, you can write a dataset that only returns video.

You will need to look (can print out) the notebook to see how the author has processed from an original video into a data sample used as input for the model. As seen in the `train_iter` function, `data` is preprocessed video and `target` is the label.

```
for i, (data,_ , target) in enumerate(data_load):
    out = F.log_softmax(model(data.cuda()), dim=1)
    loss = F.nll_loss(out, target.cuda())
```

I hope it is useful for you.